# Save grouped product : Requested product doesn't exist

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, grouped-products, save

I am getting an error in a external script when I am trying to save a grouped product : something goes wrong with product save method, the exception is "Requested product doesn't exist".

[image]

Doing unit test for one grouped product, get all associated products for this one and then rebuild links. Then save the grouped product.

```
//START TEST
$productId = 7986;
$associated = array();
$position = 0;
$productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');

$product = $productRepository->getById($productId);
$childrenProducts = $product->getTypeInstance()->getAssociatedProducts($product);

foreach($childrenProducts as $item) {
  $position++;

  $childrenId = $item->getId();
  $linkedProduct = $productRepository->getById($childrenId);

  //@var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkInterface $productLink
  $productLink = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkInterface::class);
  echo $linkedProduct->getSku().'<br />';
  echo $linkedProduct->getTypeId().'<br />';

  $productLink->setLinkType('associated')
    ->setLinkedProductSku($linkedProduct->getSku())
    ->setLinkedProductType($linkedProduct->getTypeId())
    ->setPosition($position)
    ->getExtensionAttributes();

  $associated[] = $productLink;
  $j++;
}

$product->setProductLinks($associated);
$product->save();
$i++;
//END TEST
```

Started from this script : http://www.w3solver.com/magento-2-add-a-grouped-product-programmatically/#

Please note :

- The grouped product has an SKU and is active
- Run reindex and refresh cache didn't change nothing

What's going wrong ?

Magento CE 2.2.2

Comment: Did you create child product for this group product?

Comment: Can you please add try cache in your script when you load product using **getById()** ?